# Algebra in Python

Tags: python, algebra

If I had a string like this: "2p, 8p, 12p, 17p"

And if I had a substitute for 'p', e.g: 5, could I be able to substitute this into:
"10, 40, 60, 85"?

I apologise if I am not clear, I can try to elaborate in the comments.

Comment: given the input `s` : `', '.join([str(int(e.replace('p', '')) * 5) for e in s.split(', ')])`

Comment: There is a general puthon library for symbolic mathematics called `sympy`, which can do this and many other more advanced things. The learned curve is higher, so it may not be for you if your question is all you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but not in a very nice way, if you are sure your strings have this format you can use something like that

```
s = "2p, 8p, 12p, 17p"
p = 5
result = ", ".join([str(int(i.replace("p", "")) * p) for i in s.split(", ")])
```

Otherwise you have to do a series of extra checks